# savetrees + mathptmx error?

Tags: mathptmx, capacity, savetrees

Why does the following fail to compile?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[subtle]{savetrees}

\title{Test}
\author{Foo}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Foo foo foo
\end{document}
```

If either `mathptmx` or `savetrees` is commented out, pdflatex compiles the file successfully.

This is the compilation log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathptmx.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/savetrees/savetrees.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(./main.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-ptm.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ztmcm.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omlztmcm.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omsztmcm.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omxztmcm.fd)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
pickup@font ...relax define@newfont fi begingroup
                                                  escapechar m@ne MT@let@cn ...
l.11 \maketitle

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.
```

Thanks!

Comment: it works without error for me (texlive 2017)

Comment: you only show the terminal output not the log so I can not see your package versions, I used `Package: savetrees 2016/04/13 v2.4 Pack as much text as possible onto each page`

Comment: Yes, I use the same version of savetrees, and `mathptmx 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Times w/ Math, improved (SPQR, WaS)`.

I am using texlive 2016 - will try upgrading. FWIW, I encountered this problem in ShareLatex originally.